# How to refactor this deadlock issue?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, deadlock

I ran into a deadlock issue `synchronizing` a table multiple times in a short period of time.  By synchronize I mean doing the following:

1. Insert data to be synchronized into a temp table
2. Update existing records in destination table
3. Insert new records into the destination table
4. Delete records that are not in the synch table under certain
   circumstances
5. Drop temp table

For the `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements, I'm using a LEFT JOIN similar to:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table (fk1, fk2, val1)
FROM #tmp
LEFT JOIN destination_table dt ON dt.fk1 = #tmp.fk1
   AND dt.fk2 = #temp.fk2
WHERE dt.pk IS NULL;
```

The deadlock graph is reporting the destination_table's primary key is under an exclusive lock.  I assume the above query is causing a table or page lock instead of a row lock.  How would I confirm that?

I could rewrite the above query with an `IN`, `EXIST` or `EXCEPT` command.  Are there any additional ways of refactoring the code?  Will refactoring using any of these commands avoid the deadlock issue?  Which one would be the best?  I'm assuming `EXCEPT`.

Comment: Is this all done in a transaction? What transaction isolation level are you using? Is there other activity using the destination table?

Answer (score 0):

Well under normal circumstances I could execute scenario pretty well. Given below is the test script I created. Are you trying something else?

```
drop table #destination_table
drop table #tmp

Declare @x int=0

create table #tmp(fk1 int, fk2 int, val int)

set @x=2

while (@x<1000)
begin
    insert into #tmp
    select @x,@x,100
    set @x=@x+3
end

create table #destination_table(fk1 int, fk2 int, val int)
while (@x<1000)
begin
    insert into #destination_table
    select @x,@x,100
    set @x=@x+1
end



INSERT INTO #destination_table (fk1, fk2, val)
select t.*
FROM #tmp t
LEFT JOIN #destination_table dt ON dt.fk1 = t.fk1
     AND dt.fk2 = t.fk2
WHERE dt.fk1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Since your test only uses local temporary tables accessed from a single connection it is a _little_ less likely to create a deadlock.